# Make URL alias in Wordpress (or .htaccess)

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site running on Wordpress, and I want to create one custom short-url.

If a page URL is www.mysite.com/category/post I want the user to be able to visit www.mysite.com/alias

If there is a 'Wordpress-y' way of doing things, that would be preferable, but I am also able to do it by modifying the .htaccess file.

Thanks

Comment: For one-off thing, WP plugin would probably be easiest solution ie. https://wordpress.org/plugins/swerve/

Comment: I'll check that out, but I would like to avoid plugins if possible. The site I'm working on has many idiosyncrasies!

Comment: AFAIK, except for optionally changing your permalink structure globally WP doesn't have native way of setting aliases and I don't know is this possible with just PHP (I'm not backend dev.) so I would either use a plugin or add rewrite rule in .htaccess

Comment: Yup I'm happy to do it in .htaccess, do you know how to do it this way? I'm also not a back-end. :)

Comment: @JackWild what have you tried so far? Post your current .htaccess file

Comment: sorry for the delay, please see my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^alias$ category/post [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that changes are to .htaccess file, since question asks whether this file should be modified or not.

Comment: Caution about editing Rewrite rules in the .htaccess file:  certain administrative actions can restore-to-default the top "wordpress part" of the .htaccess file, thereby eliminating any changes that you've made to this section.  For example, sometimes a plugin update can restore the top of the .htaccess file to its default.  Be careful how you edit the .htaccess file or consider a plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is a bit of an old post, and already has an accepted answer, but for those of us not wanting to (or unable to) play with the .htaccess file, it should be noted that there are several viable plugins in this space.

I've used https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/ which has 800,000+ installs. There's also https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/ with 200,000+ installs as well as several others with smaller install bases available at https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/redirect/.