# How to create a Page alias in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

[image]

In the image you see... Wordpress has alias for Pages like **Home Page**, **Checkout Page**, **Privacy Policy Page** and they appear beside the page you assign them.

So, How do I create this feature in wordpress If I want to alias a page like **XYZ Page** and when I assign any page to that alias... **XYZ Page** appears beside the assigned page.

Comment: Do you want to use plugin or custom code?

Comment: it is called `post_state`, you can add/change them with filters.

Comment: `add_filter('display_post_states', 'your_custom_fuction_here');`

Comment: Wordpress stackexchange has an example here : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/240088/82677

Answer (score 0):

*(two years later)*

I had to research this lately as well. It seems you have three options.

### Custom code

Writing a custom Plugin using `add_rewrite_rule()`:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213016/access-the-same-page-from-multiple-urls-wildcard

### .htaccess

Add rewrite rules to the `.htaccess` file:
[Make URL alias in Wordpress (or .htaccess)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444739/make-url-alias-in-wordpress-or-htaccess)

### Wordpress Plugin

I haven't tried it personally, but its feature list seems to fit your needs:
https://www.custompermalinks.com/